# Contains in Linq statement not retrieving information

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-6

Using this statement I am not getting any data:

```
Dim sFilter As String = "16,22,34"
e.QueryableSource = New myworkspace.myentity().mytable.Where(Function(p) sFilter.Split(",").Contains(p.mytablekey))
```

whereas I am with this statement (or with keys 22 or 34):

```
e.QueryableSource = New myworkspace.myentity().mytable.Where(Function(p) p.mytablekey= 16)
```

Why is the former statement not giving the desired result?

Comment: @Corobori If you use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) and correct any problems it finds, does the code work?

Comment: The 2nd statement is working just fine, that is the "Where(Function(p) sFilter.Split(",").Contains(p.mytablekey))"  which isn't retrieving the information I am expecting

Comment: `sFilter.Split(",")` returns an array of strings. `p.mytablekey= 16` suggests that `p.mytablekey` is an integer. Between the two of them, at least one of them is wrong.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you, your comment put me on the right track.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Missed the vb.net. Why didn't the first statement give a type error?

Comment: @NetMage If Option Strict is off, it is free to change types to make them match. It doesn't have to change them the way that is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

```
Dim iKeys = New Integer() {16, 22, 24}
e.QueryableSource = New ProcaseSGC.ProcaseSGCEntities1().Tbl_Contacto.Where(Function(p) iKeys.Contains(p.F_CtoCod))
```